# Why block with add node form returnes errors?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, blocks

To show add node form in particular place I created a new block on the Block page with content:

```
<?php  
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'foto', 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
$form = drupal_get_form('foto_node_form',$node);
print drupal_render($form);
?>
```

Then I go to my page with this block and try to add content within this block. When I fill only text fields or checkboxes everything is OK. But I receive a lot of errors when try to upload an image to image field.

```
•Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'node_form' was given in function drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 in file D:\sites\mytheme\www\includes\form.inc).
•Notice: Undefined index: #node in function comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1194 in fileD:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
•Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in function comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1211 in fileD:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
•Notice: Undefined index: #node in function menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 in file D:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\menu\menu.module).
•Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in function menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 in fileD:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\menu\menu.module).
•Notice: Undefined index: #node in function menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 in file D:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\menu\menu.module).
•Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in function menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 in fileD:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\menu\menu.module).
•Notice: Undefined index: field_image in function file_ajax_upload() (line 271 in file D:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\file\file.module).
•Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in function file_ajax_upload() (line 280 in file D:\sites\mytheme\www\modules\file\file.module).
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's already [answered][1] here. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page

Comment: yes, I saw it, but I cannot understand where to put 'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
'file' => 'node.pages.inc', ?

Comment: should it be in module.info file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of custom code, you can use [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module for that. It provides node creation forms in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('foto');
$output = drupal_render($form);
```

Source: [How to display node/add/sometype form on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740337/55075)